# Can FirebaseFirestore be used in an iOS app extension?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, ios-app-extension

I'm trying to use Firestore in a Swift iOS app extension

Firestore works fine in the main app, but Firestore.firestore() returns nil in the app extension

When I step through in the debugger, I see that Firestore is not a registered component

**Main app:**

```
- (nullable id)instanceForProtocol:(Protocol *)protocol {

self    FIRComponentContainer * 0x28359e1f0 0x000000028359e1f0
_app    FIRApp *    0x28359e250 0x000000028359e250
_components __NSDictionaryM *   5 key/value pairs   0x0000000283bdc2c0
[0] (null)  @"FIRInstanceIDInstanceProvider" : (no summary) 
[1] (null)  @"FSTFirestoreMultiDBProvider" : (no summary)   
[2] (null)  @"FIRAnalyticsInterop" : (no summary)   
[3] (null)  @"FIRAuthInterop" : (no summary)    
[4] (null)  @"FIRMessagingInstanceProvider" : (no summary)  
_cachedInstances    __NSDictionaryM *   3 key/value pairs   0x0000000283bdc2e0
_eagerProtocolsToInstantiate    NSMutableArray *    nil 0x0000000000000000
protocol    Protocol *  0x1056645e8 0x00000001056645e8
protocolName    __NSCFString *  @"FSTFirestoreMultiDBProvider"  0x000000028359b3c0
cachedInstance  id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
creationBlock   FIRComponentCreationBlock   0x000000010507eb40
```

**Extension:**

```
self    FIRComponentContainer * 0x11fd07ae0 0x000000011fd07ae0
NSObject    NSObject    
_app    FIRApp *    0x11fd0dd50 0x000000011fd0dd50
_components __NSDictionaryM *   1 key/value pair    0x000000011fd2a150
[0] (null)  @"FIRAuthInterop" : (no summary)    
_cachedInstances    __NSDictionaryM *   1 key/value pair    0x000000011fd2ac20
_eagerProtocolsToInstantiate    NSMutableArray *    nil 0x0000000000000000
protocol    Protocol *  0x1050ce0e8 0x00000001050ce0e8
protocolName    __NSCFString *  @"FSTFirestoreMultiDBProvider"  0x000000011fe0e540
cachedInstance  id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
creationBlock   FIRComponentCreationBlock   (null)
```

From Podfile.lock

- FirebaseFirestore (1.8.1):
- FirebaseFirestoreSwift (0.2):

I made sure FirebaseApp.configure() is called prior to Firestore.firestore()

I also added -ObjC to the extension target's Other Linker Flags, as well as the OTHER_LDFLAGS in the extensions Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/Pods*/.xcconfig

If Firestore is not supported in iOS App Extensions, would it be possible to use Firestore REST calls since Auth seems to be working in the extension?

Answer (score 2):

Solved my own problem:

I copied the "Other Linker Flags" from the main Target to the Extension target.
In the "Other Linker Flags" in the Extension Target I removed the following:

```
$(inherited)
-framework "FirebaseMessaging"
-framework "protobuf"
```

This fixed the problem.

I then changed the Extension Target's "Other Linker Flags" to be just "$(inherited) and that seemed to work as well.

It seemed like Firestore was not initializing and registering with Firebase (even though the code was linked in somehow, because I was able to step through it in the debugger)

Google devs: this would have been easier to discover if

```
- (nullable id)instanceForProtocol:(Protocol *)protocol {
```

had logged an error or thrown an exception when it could not find the protocol, instead of just returning nil

Firestore was not included in the Extension's "Other Linker Flags".  This was probably due to the way I set up my Podfile initially

**Initial Podfile:**

```
target 'XXX' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'

  target 'XXXExtension' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end

end
```

**New Podfile:**

```
target 'XXX' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'

end

target 'XXXExtension' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'

end
```

Comment: Tried your solution and still get this: Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRInstallations
Undefined symbol: _FIRInstallationIDDidChangeNotification.     Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: More complete message: Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRInstallations", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAnalytics_13f96b87f49c1be334b7be094c61ad5f.o)
  "_FIRInstallationIDDidChangeNotification", referenced from:
      +[FIRAnalytics observeFirebaseInstallationIDChanges] in FirebaseAnalytics(FIRAnalytics_13f96b87f49c1be334b7be094c61ad5f.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: I noticed redundant libraries were getting installed so I removed Firebase/Core and FirebaseFirestoreSwift. Seems it worked, however I'm having a new problem. Possibly related. My device should already be authenticated, however let user = Auth.auth().currentUser is returning nil.